# Is there a way to use a return value from a method in another method?

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to use the return value `fileName` from the method `file()`, to the method `nGram()` so I can parse the contents of the file into n-grams. I have working code to do this but I want have two seperate methods.

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    private String fileName;
    private int k;

    public Example(String fileName, int k) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.k = k;
    }

    public String file(String fileName) throws IOException {
         //Open the file.
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fr);

        // Read lines from the file till end of file
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            // Read the next line.
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            // Display the line.
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        // Close the file.
        inFile.close();
        return fileName;

    }

    private void nGram() throws IOException{
        List<String> ngrams = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= fileName.length() - k; i++) {
            ngrams.add(fileName.substring(i, i + k));
        }
        System.out.println(ngrams);
    }

//Working
//  private static void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
//      // Open the file.
//      FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
//      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fr);
//
//      // Read lines from the file till end of file
//      while (inFile.hasNext()) {
//          // Read the next line.
//          String line = inFile.nextLine();
//          // Display the line.
//          System.out.println(line);
//
//          List<String> ngrams = new ArrayList<>();
//          for (int i = 0; i <= line.length() - k; i++) {
//              ngrams.add(line.substring(i, i + k));
//          }
//          System.out.println(ngrams);
//      }
//
//      // Close the file.
//      inFile.close();
//  }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file: ");
        String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter kmers: ");
        int k = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        Example e = new Example(fileName, k);
        e.file(fileName);
        e.nGram();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello world
Good Day okay
random text saying anything me laptop bye 
[sa, am, mp, pl, le, e., .t, tx, xt]
```

Comment: First you need to remove the static modifier, you will notice you have a context problem there. Look trough non-static vs static contexts

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos i removed the static modifier

Comment: Removing `static` likely wasn't really meant to literally remove it from your question. I'd recommend reverting the edit to get a complete answer. Understanding _why_ `static` would cause problems is important.

Comment: The problem with the file() method is that it reads the file sample.txt, and then returns the String filename. You need to call ngram() within file() on each of those lines that are read.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thank you that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value returned from file(), you just need to pass a string in the nGram parameters, and call file(string) within it (because file() already returns a string).

```
private String file(String fileName){...}
private void nGram(String valueFromFile){...}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ...

    Example e = new Example(fileName, k);
    e.nGram(e.file(fileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Called the method nGram(line) in the method file().

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    private String fileName;
    private static int k;

    public Example(String fileName, int k) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.k = k;
    }

    public static String file(String fileName) throws IOException {
         //Open the file.
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fr);

        // Read lines from the file till end of file
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            // Read the next line.
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            // Display the line.
            //System.out.println(line);
            nGram(line);
        }
        // Close the file.
        inFile.close();
        return fileName;

    }

    private static void nGram(String j) throws IOException{
        List<String> ngrams = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= j.length() - k; i++) {
            ngrams.add(j.substring(i, i + k));
        }
        System.out.println(ngrams);
    }

//Working
//  private static void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
//      // Open the file.
//      FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
//      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fr);
//
//      // Read lines from the file till end of file
//      while (inFile.hasNext()) {
//          // Read the next line.
//          String line = inFile.nextLine();
//          // Display the line.
//          System.out.println(line);
//
//          List<String> ngrams = new ArrayList<>();
//          for (int i = 0; i <= line.length() - k; i++) {
//              ngrams.add(line.substring(i, i + k));
//          }
//          System.out.println(ngrams);
//      }
//
//      // Close the file.
//      inFile.close();
//  }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file: ");
        String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter kmers: ");
        int k = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        Example e = new Example(fileName, k);
        file(fileName);
    }
}
```